# Clip text label in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, labeling, clip

How can I auto clip text and append dots on a label if the current text is too long in GeoServer?
Like in GoogleMaps:
[image]
I only used AutoWrap option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`strAbbreviate` function](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) it takes 4 parameters
`the sentence`, `lower`, `upper` and `append`. It abbreviates `the sentence` at the first space beyond `lower` (or at `upper` if no space is found)and appends the `append` string if string is abbreviated.

```
      <Label>
          <ogc:Function name="strAbbreviate">
            <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>...</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>

        </Label>
```

Here is the effect of the above on the States layer names. North and South Dakota are broken at the space in their name, while Minnesota is broken at the upper limit and they all have "..." added. While Iowa and Wyoming are short enough not to be abbreviated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works great :)

Comment: then please accept the answer by clicking the "tick" beside it to tell others that it worked